# Rfid stops scanning after wrong card scanned

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, rfid

My Rfid reader stops scanning cards after scanning the wrong rfid card. It doesn't scan it anymore after turning off the relay. *It turns on the relay if my rfid card is the right one

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
#define relay 2
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.
int touchPin = 8;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
unsigned long tacc = 5000UL;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)
boolean opened = false;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(touchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  mfrc522.PCD_SetAntennaGain(mfrc522.RxGain_max);
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();
}
void loop()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  int touchValue = digitalRead(touchPin);
  if (touchValue == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
  }
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content = "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "72 02 EF E9" ) {
  Serial.println("Authorized access");
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    opened = true;
  }
  if (((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= tacc) && (opened== true)) {
  digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    opened = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `It turns on the relay if my rfid card is the right one` - more than once?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes

Comment: There is probably an error here: `if (((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= tacc)`